# How to merge 2 dict with the same key in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

How can I merge dicts with same key?

Input:
dict1:
`{ 'A': 'value1' }`

dict2:
`{ 'A': 'value2' }`

dict3:
`{ 'A': 'value3' }`

My expected output:
dict4:
`{ 'A': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] }`

How can I merge such dicts with same key in Ansible playbook?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Either *map* the *attribute* and create the dictionary

```yaml
x: "{{ {'A': [d1, d2, d3]|map(attribute='A')} }}"
```

, or use *json_query*

```yaml
x: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('{A: []. A}') }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
x1:
  A: [value1, value2, value3]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    d1: {A: value1}
    d2: {A: value2}
    d3: {A: value3}

    x1: "{{ {'A': [d1, d2, d3]|map(attribute='A')} }}"
    x2: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('{A: []. A}') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: x1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: x2|to_yaml
```

---

If you have more items in the dictionaries, for example

```yaml
    d1: {A: v10, B: v11}
    d2: {A: v20, B: v21}
    d3: {A: v30, B: v31}
```

Either use *json_query*

```yaml
x: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('{A: []. A, B: []. B}') }}"
```

, or

a) Get the keys and values

```yaml
_keys: "{{ d1|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
_vals: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('[].values(@)') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
_keys: ['A', 'B']
_vals: [['v10', 'v11'], ['v20', 'v21'], ['v30', 'v31']]
```

b) Transpose the values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        trans: "{{ trans|d(_vals.0)|zip(item)|map('flatten') }}"
      loop: "{{ _vals[1:] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
trans: [[v10, v20, v30], [v11, v21, v31]]
```

c) Create the dictionary

```yaml
x: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(trans)) }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
x:
  A: [v10, v20, v30]
  B: [v11, v21, v31]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    d1: {A: v10, B: v11}
    d2: {A: v20, B: v21}
    d3: {A: v30, B: v31}

    x1: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('{A: []. A, B: []. B}') }}"
    _keys: "{{ d1|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
    _vals: "{{ [d1, d2, d3]|json_query('[].values(@)') }}"
    x2: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(trans)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          _keys: {{ _keys }}
          _vals: {{ _vals }}

    - set_fact:
        trans: "{{ trans|d(_vals.0)|zip(item)|map('flatten') }}"
      loop: "{{ _vals[1:] }}"

    - debug:
        var: trans|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: x1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: x2|to_yaml
```